# Fancybox and form submisson in php?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

how to save the data in fancy box while submitting a form and after submitting I want to save the data in the form,in which i have given form action?

when i click submit button in form a fancy box should appear. in which we can insert data, when we click  save in the fancy box that data in fancy box and the data in the form also should be submitted?

How to do this? I have tried with

```
document.forms["form1"].submit();
```

but it didn't work.Data in fancy box is getting saved,but the data in form is not getting saved.Action is not performing.

Thanks in advance!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Replace the form element in your fancybox with a div, and move that div and its inputs between the form tags on the page.

This will submit everything on the page and in the fancybox at once.